# Configuration file error while hosting Sageframe website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis, content-management-system, sageframe

I have downloaded [SageFrameV2.1](http://sageframe.codeplex.com/) and try to host the site in my local IIS Server. Soon, I came up with a problem while browsing the site.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

[image]

And also suggests :

```
Config Error    There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined .
```

But Initially at the installation period I commented all the code starting and ending with `sectionGroup` and finally installed.

But now while I am using the framework for extra development I have uncommented previously commented portions of code. But, still my browser is suggesting the same problem. I have seen thoroughly but cannot find the duplicate as suggested by browser.

Please help me to get rid of it. I need it for the development task.

Thankful to your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your default pool in IIS is  v4.0.
SageFrameV2.1  in Codeplex is built on asp.net framework 3.5 so you can use pool 2.0 to get rid of that error.

Comment: Is there any way to host it in AppPool ASP.NET v4.0.

Comment: you need to build `SageFrame` in `.net 4.0` With the help of `VisualStudio 10` or higher verson.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your pool from `.net 4.0` to `.net 2.0`.